# UI Path Error: for "Select Item: Activity, Attribute not supported by the current UiNode

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I'm using Ui Path and trying to automate an manual work, which filling the fields in the website URL page from an excel sheet.(FYI: I've put all the required fields texts/numbers in the required format in this excel)

In the website page (using Mozilla Firefox) to fill one of the field, in UiPath workflow I've used the activity "Select Item", and for the "Item to select" I gave the variable name which was created (this variable should pull the data from excel for this activity).

Error/problem: The RPA goes to the field in the webpage precisely and click on the empty field, but does not type the data stored in the variable, instead it types last letter of the variable name. (for example if variable name is Sales, RPA bot types 's' in the field)

Error message I see in UiPath: "Select Item: Activity, Attribute not supported by the current UiNode

Instead of "Select Item" activity, I also tried with "Type Into", still the Bot does not read and write the data from variable

I've also cross checked strict selector, target and other aspects in the properties, everything looks fine.

Need your assistance here.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Hi welcome and a good description. Is there a chance we can see that website?